# What exactly does ColorTranslator.FromHtml() support and why does it deviate from CSS color interpretation rules?

Tags: c#, css, .net, colors

I want to add an option to an API for the user to specify the colour of something. I would like it to accept reasonable representations of colours, probably including hex representations and also the various CSS colours. At first glance `ColorTranslator.FromHtml()` appeared to be what I needed, but after a little experimentation I'm not so sure.

[The MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.colortranslator.fromhtml(v=vs.110).aspx), read incautiously, would seem to suggest that `ColorTranslator.FromHtml()` should support CSS colour specifications. However, it doesn't appear to support every syntax provided by CSS. For example, this will throw an exception:

```
// "rgb(255 is not a valid value for Int32"
Color c = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("rgb(255,255,255)");
```

Other colours are parsed differently to the rules for CSS found [here](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color/). An 8-digit hex code is interpreted as AARRGGBB instead of RRGGBBAA:

```
Color c = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#aabbccdd");
// 187, 204, 221, 170
Console.WriteLine($"{c.R}, {c.G}, {c.B}, {c.A}");
```

A 4-digit hex code is interpreted as RRGG (with the blue part being zero) rather than RGBA:

```
Color c = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#abcd");
// 0, 171, 205, 0
Console.WriteLine($"{c.R}, {c.G}, {c.B}, {c.A}");
```

Why do these deviations exist and what exactly does the method support? Is it just that the method is old and frozen at an older version of CSS, but with some extensions tacked on that clash with more recent CSS standards?

Comment: No part of the documentation suggests that it supports any formats that you have specified. "This method translates a string representation of an HTML color name, such as Blue or Red, to a GDI+ Color structure."

Comment: @ndonohoe, and yet it supports strings like "#aabbcc" and gives the result one might expect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't tell you why but I can tell you what is supported.

If you read the [Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Advanced/ColorTranslator.cs,000c75cae51dfd2c) you can see how the colours are handled, essentially:

- `#771122` handled as `#RRGGBB`
- `#712` handled as `#RGB`
- `LightGrey` converted to `LightGray`
- Any system colour names such as `highlighttext` are converted to specific colours.
- Any other colour name will just be created using `Color.FromName` (I think)

This is from a time before most of the things you were referring to even existed in the spec I think.

Answer (score 1):

Incase someone needs this in the future.
Manual parsing of HTML/CSS colors to Color?   (nullable color)
May need to translate to C#.
May need to add support for more formats, but this covers the typical base cases for 99% of web styling i think.

```
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Named groups "r", "g", "b".
    ''' </summary>
    Private Shared Regex_Html_RRGGBB As New Regex("^#(?<r>[0-9a-f][0-9a-f])(?<g>[0-9a-f][0-9a-f])(?<b>[0-9a-f][0-9a-f])$", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture Or RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.Compiled)

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Named groups "r", "g", "b".
    ''' </summary>
    Private Shared Regex_Html_RGB As New Regex("^#(?<r>[0-9a-f])(?<g>[0-9a-f])(?<b>[0-9a-f])$", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture Or RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.Compiled)

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Named groups "r", "g", "b".
    ''' </summary>
    Private Shared Regex_Html_RGB_funct As New Regex("^rgb\((?<r>[0-255]{1,3})[\t ]*,[\t ]*(?<g>[0-255]{1,3})[\t ]*,[\t ]*(?<b>[0-255]{1,3})\)$", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture Or RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.Compiled)

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Named groups "r", "g", "b", "a" where A is only 0-1 range decimal.
    ''' </summary>
    Private Shared Regex_Html_RGBA_funct As New Regex("^rgba\((?<r>[0-255]{1,3})[\t ]*,[\t ]*(?<g>[0-255]{1,3})[\t ]*,[\t ]*(?<b>[0-255]{1,3}),[\t ]*(?<a>[0-1][\.]{0,1}[0-9]{0,9})\)$", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture Or RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.Compiled)

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Reverse convertion from css format color to drawing color.
    ''' Supported formats #RRGGBB, #RGB, rgb(i,i,i), rgba(i,i,i,d), Named Colors.
    ''' Returns Nothing on failure.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="value"></param>
    Public Shared Function FromHtmlColor(value As String) As Color?
        If value.IsNullOrWhitespace Then
            Return Nothing
        Else ' must parse
            ' color translator doesn't account for transparancy.
            ' must check manually first.
            Dim m As Match
            m = Regex_Html_RGBA_funct.Match(value)
            If m.Success Then
                Dim r As Integer = ToRange(0, ToInt(m.Groups("r").Value), 255)
                Dim g As Integer = ToRange(0, ToInt(m.Groups("g").Value), 255)
                Dim b As Integer = ToRange(0, ToInt(m.Groups("b").Value), 255)
                Dim a As Integer = ToRange(0, ToInt(255 * ToDbl(m.Groups("a").Value)), 255) ' convert 0-1 to 0-255.
                Return Color.FromArgb(a, r, g, b)
            End If
            m = Regex_Html_RRGGBB.Match(value)
            If m.Success Then
                Dim r As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(m.Groups("r").Value, 16)
                Dim g As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(m.Groups("g").Value, 16)
                Dim b As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(m.Groups("b").Value, 16)
                Return Color.FromArgb(r, g, b)
            End If
            m = Regex_Html_RGB_funct.Match(value)
            If m.Success Then
                Dim r As Integer = ToRange(0, ToInt(m.Groups("r").Value), 255)
                Dim g As Integer = ToRange(0, ToInt(m.Groups("g").Value), 255)
                Dim b As Integer = ToRange(0, ToInt(m.Groups("b").Value), 255)
                Return Color.FromArgb(r, g, b)
            End If
            m = Regex_Html_RGB.Match(value) ' #rgb that needs values doubled before conversion.
            If m.Success Then
                Dim r As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(m.Groups("r").Value & m.Groups("r").Value, 16) ' double up each character for "#rgb"
                Dim g As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(m.Groups("g").Value & m.Groups("g").Value, 16)
                Dim b As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(m.Groups("b").Value & m.Groups("b").Value, 16)
                Return Color.FromArgb(r, g, b)
            End If
            Try ' color translator as final fallback (this supports very little surprisingly
                Return Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(value)
            Catch ex As Exception
                ' ignore.
            End Try
            Return Nothing
        End If
    End Function
```

Comment: I just noticed some extension methods in use in that.
--> string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value) ' extension on this.
--> ToRange(lower, value, upper) this just ensures the value in in the range

Answer (score -2):

Based on the fact that the method is called `FromHtml()` and not `FromCss()`, the reason that this method "deviates" from CSS standards is probably because it doesn't even attempt to implement CSS in the first place. What exactly does it support? Again, based on the method name, the method appears to be advertising support for HTML colors.

For those unfamiliar with the two languages, HTML and CSS are two distinct languages that do not intimately share the same notation for color values. The only thing they have in common are a number of predefined color names, as well as the hex notation. The fact that any given method correctly interprets 6-digit hex codes as RGB colors doesn't suggest, in any way, that the method has anything to do with CSS. Likewise, the fact that HTML accepts hex codes as color values doesn't automatically mean that it's compatible with CSS.

Case in point: HTML doesn't have an `rgb()` functional notation. HTML doesn't have 8-digit hex codes (they're simply treated as 6-digit hex codes with any trailing digits ignored). And HTML doesn't have 4-digit hex codes (they're simply treated as 6-digit hex codes with the first 4 digits filled in).

And in CSS, 8- and 4-digit hex codes are only valid in css-color-4, a relatively new standard and the same one that you link to. This method on the other hand has been around for *years*. Some browsers can claim to implement features that get standardized later on (WebKit being particularly notorious for this, but IE5 is often credited for [popularizing what would later become the `box-sizing` property](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AscendedGlitch)), but to say that this method does the same would be quite a stretch.